# Flexbox/grid layout with horizontal scroll for medium screen size

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

I have a design of the layout for three screen sizes. The html for the layout:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left-top">Left top</div>
   <div class="left-bottom">Left Bottom</div>
   <div class="center">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed velit a quam feugiat varius. Duis et euismod felis. Quisque eget feugiat nisl. Fusce iaculis massa non ante fringilla rhoncus sed nec felis. Nam consequat sem quis tellus luctus malesuada. Sed est elit, blandit at augue suscipit, auctor elementum libero. Aenean laoreet egestas leo, et pretium tellus laoreet ultricies. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
   </div>
   <div class="right-top">Right Top</div>
   <div class="right-bottom">Right Bottom</div>
</div>
```

For the big screen css for items looks like this:

```css
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
          "left-top center right-top"
          "left-bottom center right-bottom"
          ". center .";
```

The left and right components have their own height and do not depend on the center component height.

[image]

For the small screen size css for the layout looks like this:

```css
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
            "left-top"
            "left-bottom"
            "center"
            "right-top"
            "right-bottom";
```

All of the components just go in the column.
[image]

The biggest problem is layout for the medium screen and I don't know how to do it.

The left and right components should be with the fixed width and scroll. And the central component should be width 'width: 100%' and not scrollable.

Layout for the medium screen size should looks like this:
[image]

## Question:

How grid should be for the left and right items to scroll horizontally and centred item to be full screen?

## I've tried:

[Codepen link on what I've tried.](https://codepen.io/alisaliso/pen/xxRQbwy?editors=1100)
I've tried to set display for the wrapper for medium screen size to the flex and change the order of each component but the left and right components should be with fixed width and scroll and the center component should be with 'width: 100%' and depend on screen width.
The code I've tried:

```css
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  
  .left-top, .right-top, .left-bottom, .right-bottom {
    width: 400px;
  }
  
  .left-top {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .left-bottom {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .right-top {
    order: 3;
  }
  
  .right-bottom {
    order: 4;
  }
  
  .center {
    order: 5;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: doesnt work they way you think it work. The left and right elements would have to be in a different container that allows to be overflow. as long as thsoe component are within the same container as the main content, they both will be able to overflow and scroll or none. because the overflow happens to the container not to those child elements.

Comment: If the left and right elements is in the different container and center component is outside of this component is there a way to place the center component between left and right components with flex box or grid?

Comment: "How grid should be for the left and right items to scroll horizontally and centred item to be full screen?" - you have a single wrapper parent, if you want different wrapper 'reactions' (scroll vs non scroll) simultaneously, you'll need individual wrappers for each zone/area where you want to see the different behaviour